# Changing a dynamically created label's text with keyup() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onkeyup

I am creating a form dynamically and therefore edit the form elements’ properties. When attempting to change the label, assigning an auto-generated id works fine but when changing this label using the generated id, the function or `keyup()` from jQuery keeps calling all the previously created label id(s). this means when i want to edit one label, it ends up editing every label.

#### HTML

```html
<input type="text" id="change-label"><br><br>
<button id="add-button">add label</button>
<div id="add-label"></div>
```

#### JavaScript/jQuery

```js
$('#add-button').click(function(){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var textLabel = document.createElement('label');
    var labelNode = document.createTextNode('untitled');
    textLabel.appendChild(labelNode);
    textLabel.id = autoIdClosure();
    $('#change-label').val('untitled');
    div.appendChild(textLabel);
    $('#add-label').append(div);
});
var autoIdClosure = (function(){
    var counter = 0;
    var labelId = "textInputLabel";
    return function(){
        counter += 1;
        var id = labelId + counter;
        editLabelWrapper(id)
        return id;
    }
})();
function editLabelWrapper(id){
    function editLabel(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $("#"+id).text(value);
    }
    $("#change-label").keyup(editLabel).keyup();
}
```

I’ve already found an alternative using `onkeyup="$('#'+globaID).text($(this).val());"`, but I need to understand what I was doing wrong so I can learn from it.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r0utu7as/)**

Comment: What is the desired behavior? Do you want only the last label to be editable?

Comment: yes, only the last added label should be up for editing.

Comment: but i already have that behavior so really what i want is an explanation of what i did wrong and how to correct it..

Comment: In your original code, the `#change-label` element has as many event listeners as labels you have on the screen, each listener points to a function that changes a different label. For example if you have two labels, one and two, and a `keyup` event occurs - it is actually handled twice - once for the first ID and another time for the second ID.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overthinking the matter...

Instead of using an unique id, rather use classes, makes it easier to handle.
So change `<div id="add-label"></div>` to `<div class="add-label"></div>`

Then what you want to do is, when a value is given in `#change-label` you want it in the last `div.add-label`.

So the function will become this:

```
$("#change-label").on('keyup', function() {
    $('.add-label:last').text( $(this).val() );
});
```

Next what you want to do is bind a function to `#add-button`. Once it gets clicked, we want to add a new `div.add-label` after the last one. And empty the `#change-label`. You can do that by using this function:

```
$('#add-button').on('click', function() {
    $('.add-label:last').after('<div class="add-label"></div>');
    $('#change-label').val('');
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/r0utu7as/4/)

Comment: this is a cool solution. but i kind of want to understand what the problem was with the submitted code. i've already found an alternative way of doing it successfully(although your way is better)